# SFML square's off set

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to sfml/c++. I am trying to display a yellow square on a chess board at piece's first and last location. I succeed in that but my square isn't completely overlapped on the chess board's square. It's look kind an unnatural. here's my texture class and main function(with photo).

**main function:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RectangleShape.hpp>
#include "TEXTURE.h"
#include "SOUND.h"


using namespace sf;


int main()
{
    TEXTURE tex;
    SOUND sou;

    RenderWindow Window(VideoMode(850,850),"JIMMY CHESS",Style::Titlebar|Style::Close);

    Window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    Window.setFramerateLimit(60);


        tex.setimages();
        tex.setpieces();

        while(Window.isOpen())
        {
            Event e;

            Vector2i POS = Mouse::getPosition(Window);

            while(Window.pollEvent(e))
            {

                if(e.type==Event::Closed)
                {
                    Window.close();
                }

                tex.liftpiece(e,POS);

            }

            tex.droppiece(POS);

            Window.clear();

            Window.draw(tex.s1);

            Window.draw(tex.yellown);
            Window.draw(tex.yellowo);

            for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
            {
                Window.draw(tex.s2[i]);
            }
            //layer 1 : chess board
            Window.display();

        }

    return 0;
}
```

**texture.h :(not full texture.h)**

```
Texture board,piece,yellow1,yellow2;
Sprite s1;
Sprite s2[32];
Sprite yellown,yellowo;
```

**texture's function :**

```
void TEXTURE::setimages()
{
    board.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\JIMMY RATHWA\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DAIICT\\CODE BLOCKS PROJECT\\CHESS\\images\\chessboard.png");
    piece.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\JIMMY RATHWA\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DAIICT\\CODE BLOCKS PROJECT\\CHESS\\images\\chesspiece.png");
    yellow1.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\JIMMY RATHWA\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DAIICT\\CODE BLOCKS PROJECT\\CHESS\\images\\OLDsquare.png");
    yellow2.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\JIMMY RATHWA\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DAIICT\\CODE BLOCKS PROJECT\\CHESS\\images\\OLDsquare.png");

    s1.setTexture(board);

    s1.setOrigin(425,425);
    s1.setPosition(425,425);

    yellown.setTexture(yellow1);
    yellowo.setTexture(yellow2);

    yellown.setTextureRect(IntRect(10,10,106,106));
    yellowo.setTextureRect(IntRect(10,10,106,106));

    piece.setSmooth(true);

    for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        s2[i].setTexture(piece);
    }
}
```

**this is the square looks like :**

[this yellow square isn't fitting into the chess board's square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Degf9.png)

so please give an suggestion on that!thank you for help and sorry for bad inglish ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to load 4 texture files, since you are loading twice the same one (OLDsquare.png). You can just use setTexture() with the same sf::Texture for the two Sprites yellown and yellowo.(You can even make it only one file to load by putting all your textures in one file and telling the Sprites where to get their textures in the file with sprite.setTextureRect(), which you already do for the yellown and yellowo sprites)

Secondly I recommend that you do not use sf::Sprite but sf::RectangleShape instead, since there is basically no difference except that RectangleShape are lighter and more easy to use (especially when it comes to setting size).

Third, I think your code organization is a little bit weird. You probably should have a Chessboard class and a piece class, with their own methods instead of having a "TEXTURE" class with everything in it.

Lastly, I do not seem to see where you set the position of the pieces and the yellown, maybe it's in the setPieces() method ? Beause the problem is likely coming from here.

Comment: bro thank you answering this question. I appreciate you lot. your first point I understood well. in second point I tried to make a square shape from Rectangle shape, but it's require vector2f parameter in it, and in my code I don't know why vector2f is not working properly so i came up with this square sprite solution, and third point i am new to the game development. this the first game i am making ,so i have very poor understanding about code organization. Thank you for giving me this respect full answer. THANK YOU :)

Comment: @JimmY No problem =)
I know that it can be strange to get used to the vector2 but it's actually really simple once you get used to it, it's just 2 floats passed together, you doesn't even need to store the data in vector2. For example if you want to set the size of a RectangleShape and you have 2 floats for the coords, you can write if like that :
`float x = 50;
float y = 200;
sf::RectangleShape shape;
shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
`